# Want to drag gltf objects

Tags: arrays, object, three.js, draggable, gltf

I want to drag this two GLTF objects

```
{const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
const url = 'resources/models/bookshelf2/bookshelf2.glb';
gltfLoader.load(url, (gltf) => {const root = gltf.scene;
scene.add(root);});

const url2 = 'resources/models/bookshelf2/bookshelf2.glb';
gltfLoader.load(url2, (gltf) => {const root2 = gltf.scene;
scene.add(root2);
root2.position.set(10,0,0);});

const dragcontrols = new Dragcontrols([root, root2], camera, renderer.domElement);}
```

I got an error. root is not defined.
how can I drag objects using Dragcontrols?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you don't wait for your GLTF models to finish loading.

You should add the 3D objects to the controls when the callback is executed.

This should correct your problem :

```
    {
        const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
        const url = 'resources/models/bookshelf2/bookshelf2.glb';
        gltfLoader.load(url, (gltf) => {
            const root = gltf.scene;
            scene.add(root);

            const url2 = 'resources/models/bookshelf2/bookshelf2.glb';
            gltfLoader.load(url2, (gltf) => {
                const root2 = gltf.scene;
                scene.add(root2);
                root2.position.set(10, 0, 0);

                const dragcontrols = new Dragcontrols([root, root2], camera, renderer.domElement);
            })
        })
    }
```